# Inverse mapping from a Python list-of-lists to an integer index

Tags: python, list

I have a list in Python that expresses the best store to find a specific product, like this (we only return the list below):

```
Index: Product     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
Value: Store      [5, 6, 1, 7, 3, 4, 2, 0, 8, 9]
```

Right now, each product has a unique store, so I can convert it into a list of lists that indexes the stores and the products to buy in each:

```
Index: Store               0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
Value: List of Products  [[7], [2], [6], [4], [5], [0], [1], [3], [8], [9]]
```

using this function:

```
def convertList(l):
    return [[i] for (i, j) in sorted(list(enumerate(l)), key=lambda e:e[1])]
```

But now I'm at a loss as to how to combine them for the case where multiple products are best found in one store (in this case, products 3 and 9 are best at store 7, and nothing should be bought at store 9) :

```
Index: Product     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
Value: Store      [5, 6, 1, 7, 3, 4, 2, 0, 8, 7]
```

The output should look like:

```
Index: Store               0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7       8    9
Value: List of Products  [[7], [2], [6], [4], [5], [0], [1], [3, 9], [8], []]
```

I know I'm stuck at the sorted function in convertList, but I'm not sure how to proceed. I'm practicing list comprehensions, so I'd like to use one if it's feasible. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks to all respondents: I'm sure I got into a frame of mind where, because I was focused on list comprehensions, I was sure this both could and needed to be resolved using one. Kind of like the phrase, "When you have a hammer, everything looks like a nail."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will be more readable without using a list comprehension. List comprehensions work well for one-to-one mapping steps, which this is not.

Best to loop over your input and add each item to the right element of your output array:

```
# assuming your input is in product_to_store
store_to_product = [[] for i in range(10)]
for product, store in enumerate(product_to_store):
  store_to_product[store].append(product)
```

Answer (score 2):

Honestly this feels like a time for a defaultdict and not a list.

A defaultdict will return a default value for any key that doesn't exist - that value can be None, 'hello world', or a list. (the value has to be callable, so if you really wanted a default string you might encapsulate it in a lambda or some such, but the idea is the same)

```
from collections import defaultdict

mydict = defaultdict(list)
mydict['Store_1'].append(product) #automatically creates list for this entry if one does not exist
```

From here you can simply iterate over your list and assign them to keys as indexes. Integers can be used as dict keys, so there's no issue.

```
for store, product in enumerate(my_list):
    mydict[store].append(product)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler option is a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

stores = defaultdict(list)

for store, product in enumerate(list_of_products):
    for p in product:
        stores[store].append(product)
```

Comment: D'oh, you're about two minutes faster than me :)

Answer (score 1):

Wrote a quick program that does that. First two will create your data, the last will sort based on your index.

```
array = []
map = []

# get random array
for j in range(0, 10):
    array.append(random.randint(0, 9))

# initialize to empty
for i in range(0, 10):
    map.append([])

# sort
for i in range(0, len(array)):
    temp = [i]
    map[array[i]] = map[array[i]] + temp


print(array)
print(map)
```

Will output something like:

```
[3, 7, 7, 2, 1, 6, 0, 8, 6, 5]
[[6], [4], [3], [0], [], [9], [5, 8], [1, 2], [7], []]
```